# Could Radix Sort be used to tackle LCS algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, radix-sort, longest-common-substring

Could one use the Radix Sort to find the Longest Common Subsequence problem? I am new to algorithms and was wondering if the string was converted to a list and then one was able to apply Radix Sort and instead of sorting able to search for the longest common subsequence by matching up the positions. Or would this be an improper application of Radix Sort in this problem?

##Edit

My original thought was that if the one created buckets to store the association if the sequences were of the same length. Increasing the length of LCS by reading the string left to right. If that helps to answer the question.

Comment: Could you explain how the sorted sequences would help you find the longest common subsequence? (I mean how do you construct the LCS form the sorted sequences?)

Comment: Do you by any chance have something like this in mind: https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-array.html#on-log-n-approach (construction of suffix array using radix sort)? It won't work for subsequences, since their symbols are not consecutive.

Comment: @Dmitry Your comment actually answers my question please post it as an answer.